# How to display pdf file with multiple thumbnails on a webpage using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdf

I am working on a project at work where on one page I have displayed multiple pdf thumbnails/images which have been loaded dynamically from a directory my system. Each thumbnail has respective pdf file in other directory.

So, when I click on any one of the thumbnails/images on the webpage, the respective pdf file should open on new window which is also stored at a different directory on  the system.  I have used php to develop my webpage....

```
<?php
//FOR PDF
$pdf_directory = "pdf/";// PDF file directory
$p = glob($pdf_directory."*");

foreach($p as $portable) {  
    $file=basename($portable,"*.pdf");
    $without_ex1 = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME); 

    //FOR THUMBNAIL
    $pdfimg_directory = "pdfimage/";// THUMBNAIL Directory
    $pi = glob($pdfimg_directory."*");

    $file2 = basename($b,"*.pdf");
    $without_ex2 = pathinfo($file2, PATHINFO_FILENAME); //trim .jgp
    if($without_ex1===$without_ex2) {
        foreach($pi as $thumbImages) {
            echo '<a href="'.$portable.'"<img id = "img_id" src="'.$thumbImages.'" style="width: 100; height:100;">';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is just HTML. So have you put your thumbnail in an anchor tag? Showing us what you have dont would also be quite useful..... **We are not clairvoyant**

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yeah i tried... but there are multiple thumbnails. Each thumbnail has a respective pdf. So whenever the user clicks on any image it should open that particular pdf.

Comment: **So show us an example of your HTML**

Comment: just edited my post.. please check

Comment: Try adding the folder where the file is stored to the `href` like this `echo '<a href="' . $pdf_directory . $portable . '` Remember the browser has to find the file on your server

Comment: Do you actually see any thumbnails images  when viewing the page in a browser? The thumbnail images appear to be inside the anchor tag attribute list instead of between opening and closing `<a>` and `</a>` tags. (See  [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Creating_a_clickable_image))

Comment: I created a thumbnail for the pdf using imagemagick. So the pdf preview or thumbnail is the link to that particular pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired output. Thank you for your help.
Shared the code below.

```
<?php 
        $pdf = "pdf/";      //pdf directory
        $pdfimg = "pdfimage/"; //pdf thumbnail directory. Used imagemagick to convert pdf to thumbnail
        $all_files = glob($pdfimg."*"); 
        $all_pdf = glob($pdf."*pdf");
            for ($i=0;$i<count($all_files);$i++){
                $pdf_name = $all_pdf[$i];
                $a = ltrim($pdf_name,"pdf/"); //display pdf name
                $image_name = $all_files[$i]; 
                echo '<a href="'.$pdf_name.'"><img src="'.$image_name .'" alt="'.$image_name.'" title="'.$a.'"style="height:100; width:100;display:inline;animation: moveSlideShow 1s linear infinite; margin-top:-17px; margin-left:5px;"/></a>';
            }   
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question does not have much code or much information but I think this is what you are looking for. 
I think you want [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp) but with pdf files as well, I guess you can edit the code and make it suitable for pdf. Here is a code snippet for the link above:

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possibly because you didn't answer the question, _and_ you expanded a link-only answer (of sorts) by copying and pasting the link.